# Softlayer API request NOT reaches to Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I run softlayer API for failover/failback (replication), I am receiving boolean status as TRUE. But when I goto Softlayer portal to confirm the request has placed properly or no, I could not see any changes in status.

### See the code below:

```
import SoftLayer

client = SoftLayer.Client()

# Define parameters for snapshot

replicantId = <primary storage ID>
replicantId1 = <replica storage ID>

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi'].immediateFailoverToReplicant(replicantId1, id=replicantId)
    print (result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error: " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

---

Above code returns me 'TRUE', but I could not see any changes on portal.

Also, when I check the replication status of volume with method 'getReplicationStatus' it returns 'REPLICATION_PROVISIONING_COMPLETED' for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "SoftLayer_Network_Storage" service instead "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi"

Regards

Comment: Yes, it worked with "SoftLayer_Network_Storage". Could you please tell me what is the difference between them?

Comment: There is no difference, currently there are issues wit the SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi service, I will report your issue. meanwhile I suggest you to use the SoftLayer_Network_Storage service to avoid more issues regards